# tkinter Checkbutton not working as expected

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to recreate the example as given in https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/tkinter/tkinter-checkbox-and-checkbutton, which uses the following code:

```
from tkinter import *

def click_me():
print(i.get())

root =Tk()
i=IntVar()
c = Checkbutton(root, text = "Python", variable=i)
c.pack()

b = Button(root,text="Click here",command=click_me)
b.pack()

root.geometry("400x400+120+120")
root.mainloop()
```

However, for me, it doesn't have the desired output. In the example they obtained a value of 1 for the checkbox being clicked and 0 for the checkbox being no clicked. However, I obtain a value of 0 for both when it is and is not checked. Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong been stumped for a while on this!

Versions used:

conda -- 4.10.1

tk -- 8.6.10 -- hb0a8c7a_0

spyder -- 4.2.5 -- py38hecd8cb5_0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `i = IntVar(root)`.  If it works, then the issue is due to that there are more than one instances of `Tk()`.

Comment: Oh, amazing! Works perfectly now. If you could you explain your comment about more than one instance. Is it good practice to use `i = IntVar(root)` for instance? But thanks again!

Comment: Did you import this script from another python script?  If yes, then that python script has already created an instance of Tk() most probably.

Comment: I just copied and pasted it into a new file with a new console